Find out subjects whose disease went away
I have a data frame - each individual has multiple visits. I want to find out subjects whose disease went away at some point after the first diagnosis. Disease: 1=has disease, 0=no disease.
How to create a new variable "Back_to_normal"=(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)?
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
Visit <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
Disease <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, Disease)


Hi! That won't work because some patients were like 0, 1, 0 and some were like 0, 1, 1. I want the first scenario not the second.

This code will first identify rows where that ID has had (up to that point) at least one Disease == 1, but currently has Disease == 0. That necessarily reflects an observation where at that point the ID has recovered from a prior Disease. Then it just extracts the unique IDs, since we only need one such recovery per ID.
library(dplyr)
df |>
  # arrange(visit)  # in case data is not necessarily sorted chronologically
  filter(cumsum(Disease) >= 1, Disease == 0, .by = ID) |>
  distinct(ID)

  ID
1  2
2  4
3  6

To create a new variable "Back_to_normal" that assigns 1 to patients whose disease went away and 0 to those didn't (per question in comment), you could assign the output of the code above -> recovered_IDs. Then run
df |>
  mutate(Back_to_normal = 1*(ID %in% recovered_IDs$ID))

More elegantly, as your comment suggests:
df |>
  mutate(Back_to_normal = ifelse(any(cumsum(Disease) >= 1 & Disease == 0),1,0), 
         .by = ID)


I don't know if this is doing what I want to do. Does it include patients (0,1,..,0), (1,..,1,0) and exclude patients (1,1,..,1) or (0,1,1,..,1)?

@Jenn0804 - why not test it? df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), Disease = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))

I did but it didn't work on my actual dataset. Let me do some troubleshooting

One thing, your test data was sorted by visit. If your actual data is not necessarily sorted, you should add arrange(visit) |> before the filter line. That way the cumsum will correctly count the cumulative Disease observations in chronological order.

Thank you! Will try that! How do you create a new variable "Back_to_normal" that assigns 1 to patients whose disease went away and 0 to those didn't

Thank you for your update! mutate(Back_to_normal = ifelse(any(cumsum(Disease) >= 1, Disease == 0),1,0)) why this doesn't work?

That mutate would need a .by = ID if you want the calculation to be separately applied to each ID, otherwise it would look for any Disease == 0 that follows the first Disease == 1. And you'd need an & where you have , between the tests.
